# Will Flutter work with WordPress 3.0?

Tags: plugins, customization

My WordPress admin is constantly nagging me to upgrade to version 3.0. However, we use the Flutter plugin to provide all our CMS-like features. It's a pretty great plugin, but it doesn't seem to have been under active development lately, and I hear grumblings it's not compatible with WP 3.0.

Is anyone having luck with it? Should I wait around until an updated version is released, or start thinking about re-developing features of our site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Magic Fields](http://magicfields.org) is very similar to flutter and is compatible with  WordPress 3

If do you want switch between flutter to magic  fields  you have  here a little help  for do it http://magicfields.org/script-for-migrate-from-flutter-v-1-1-and-1-0/

Comment: Great! This looks like exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend using [Magic Fields](http://magicfields.org/) - which is a fork of and built on Flutter and still under development. The latest version there says that it suports WP 3.

I believe that you should also be able to migrate the data that you have on Flutter to Magic Fields.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is set up a development version of your website that you can break with impunity. Then just try upgrading it. If it works, great! If not, it may be just small changes that are necessary to get it working. You can have a great degree of certainty about compatibility, but it's hard to be 100% sure. It's always easier to work backwards from an error than to try to preempt every possible error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magic Fields with WP3 with no problems so far. It's a lot cleaner than Flutter, they have removed a few features such as the edit in place code but I never used that anyway. Overall it just feels a lot better than Flutter due to having had a good clearout in the codebase. It works much like Flutter in regard to setting up write panels etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much benefit in upgrading to WP 3.0, so it's wise to think twice. To remove the update nag, you can use a plugin as well:

- No Update Nag Wordpress Plugin: http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/no-update-nag/